# Serve Static files w/ Javascript/Tomcat7.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

I have a .zip file that I'd like to make available for download. I have the following code (note that I'm using Angular and Eclipse/Tomcat v7.0).

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="vm.download()">Download</button>
</form>
<iframe id=dlWindow style='display:none;'>
```

~~~

```
vm.download = function(){
    document.getElementById('dlWindow').src = "ZipFile.zip";
};
```

But then when I run it and click the button, I get a 404 error.

```
GET http://localhost:8082/riv-healthcheck/app/ZipFile.zip 404 (Not Found)
```

Even though the file exists in

```
C:\projects\sts3.4.0-workspace\riv-healthcheck\WebContent\app\ZipFile.zip
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of webserver are you using? As far as I know, eclipse is just an IDE ;)

Comment: I'm using Tomcat v7.0. Added that to the question.

Comment: This sounds more like figuring out how Tomcat maps static files on to URLs than it does anything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Your links don't match though, there's a _WebContent_ after _riv-healthcheck_ in the second link address

Comment: Thinking maybe I should redo this question to ask that instead?

Comment: Sidd - I still get the same 404 if I put the file in C:\projects\sts3.4.0-workspace\riv-healthcheck\app

Comment: As Quentin said, you gotta find out how your java web framework (?) serves static files with tomcat. I would try with `C:\projects\sts3.4.0-workspace\riv-healthcheck\src\main\webapp\ZipFile.zip
` and `GET http://localhost:8082/riv-healthcheck/ZipFile.zip`

Answer (score 0):

is that your path

```
\riv-healthcheck\WebContent\app\ZipFile.zip
```

and it should be this?

```
http://localhost:8082/riv-healthcheck/WebContent/app/ZipFile.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was way off when I first wrote this question, thinking it was a JS issue when it was a Tomcat issue.

In server.xml I added this line, describing where I'd put my files.

```
<Context docBase="C:/projects/sts3.4.0-workspace/riv-healthcheck/resources" path="/resources" />
```

And then in my controller

```
vm.download = function(){
            document.getElementById('dlWindow').src = "/resources/MQUtility.zip";
```